# Applescript functions

Tags: function, applescript, keyword

Is there a difference between the `on` and `to` keywords when declaring functions in applescript? Seems like they're interchangeable from what I've seen. Is that the case or would one be more useful than the other in some situations?

Comment: All about handlers: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH

Answer (score 1):

`on` and `to` are equivalent. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html:

```
( on | to ) handlerName ¬
   [ [ of | in ] directParamName ] ¬
   [ ASLabel userParamName ]... ¬
   [ given userLabel:userParamName [, userLabel:userParamName ]...]
      [ statement ]...
end [ handlerName ]
```